# docker: 'compose' is not a docker command

Tags: macos, sonoma, docker

I installed the docker-engine in macOS from
https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/mac-install/
which says,

> The Docker Desktop installation includes Docker Engine, Docker CLI client, *Docker Compose*, Notary, Kubernetes, and Credential Helper.

But when using `docker-compose`, I'm getting:

`docker: 'compose' is not a docker command.`

What's wrong please?

Full log:

```sh
$ /Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/bin/docker -v
Docker version 24.0.7, build afdd53b

$ /Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/bin/docker-compose -v
docker: 'compose' is not a docker command.
See 'docker --help'

$ sw_vers
ProductName:            macOS
ProductVersion:         14.2.1
BuildVersion:           23C71
```

**UPDATE:**

It's an *invalid* question -- the problem is else where:

```sh
$ type docker
docker is /usr/local/bin/docker

$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/docker*
ls: cannot read symbolic link '/usr/local/bin/docker': Permission denied
ls: cannot read symbolic link '/usr/local/bin/docker-credential-desktop': Permission denied
ls: cannot read symbolic link '/usr/local/bin/docker-credential-ecr-login': Permission denied
ls: cannot read symbolic link '/usr/local/bin/docker-credential-osxkeychain': Permission denied
ls: cannot read symbolic link '/usr/local/bin/docker-index': Permission denied
lrwxr-x--x 1 root wheel 54 Feb  2 13:46 /usr/local/bin/docker
lrwxr-x--x 1 root wheel 73 Feb  2 13:46 /usr/local/bin/docker-credential-desktop
lrwxr-x--x 1 root wheel 75 Feb  2 13:46 /usr/local/bin/docker-credential-ecr-login
lrwxr-x--x 1 root wheel 77 Feb  2 13:46 /usr/local/bin/docker-credential-osxkeychain
lrwxr-x--x 1 root wheel 60 Feb  2 13:46 /usr/local/bin/docker-index
```

I.e., I symlink docker apps into /usr/local/bin/ but somehow they failed:

```sh
$ sudo rm /usr/local/bin/docker*

$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/docker*
ls: cannot access '/usr/local/bin/docker*': No such file or directory

$ sudo ln -s /Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/bin/docker /usr/local/bin

$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/docker*
ls: cannot read symbolic link '/usr/local/bin/docker': Permission denied
lrwxr-x--x 1 root wheel 54 Feb  3 15:09 /usr/local/bin/docker
```

However, I don't know how, but after I tried it several times, it is suddenly working:

```sh
$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/docker*
lrwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel 54 Feb  3 15:15 /usr/local/bin/docker -> /Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/bin/docker
lrwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel 62 Feb  3 15:15 /usr/local/bin/docker-compose -> /Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/bin/docker-compose
lrwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel 73 Feb  3 15:15 /usr/local/bin/docker-credential-desktop -> /Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/bin/docker-credential-desktop
lrwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel 75 Feb  3 15:15 /usr/local/bin/docker-credential-ecr-login -> /Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/bin/docker-credential-ecr-login
lrwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel 77 Feb  3 15:15 /usr/local/bin/docker-credential-osxkeychain -> /Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/bin/docker-credential-osxkeychain
lrwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel 60 Feb  3 15:15 /usr/local/bin/docker-index -> /Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/bin/docker-index

$ docker-compose -v
Docker Compose version v2.23.3-desktop.2
```

I don't know why it didn't work and, I don't know how it works again, so I'm accepting whatever answer I have and move on.

Comment: Instead of editing the question, can you please add the solution as an answer and upvote/accept it?

Comment: It's an invalid question @nohillside, my update is not the solution but an explanation why it is, moreover, as put into the update, _"I don't know why it didn't work and, I don't know how it works again"_, i.e., all in all, there is no solution.

Comment: There are no invalid questions ;-) Even if your solution has some gaps, it may help future visitors. But it would be easier to find if you post it as an answer.

Comment: PS: You could even turn it into a full answer by describing how /usr/local/bin must look and how to fix a botched docker install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing "Docker Desktop" adds the CLI commands to `/usr/local/bin`, so you should never need to call the binaries in `/Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/bin` directly.

```bash
$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/docker*
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin  54 Feb  6  2022 /usr/local/bin/docker@ -> /Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/bin/docker
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin  62 Feb  6  2022 /usr/local/bin/docker-compose@ -> /Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/bin/docker-compose
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin  80 Feb  6  2022 /usr/local/bin/docker-compose-v1@ -> /Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/bin/docker-compose-v1/docker-compose
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin  73 Feb  6  2022 /usr/local/bin/docker-credential-desktop@ -> /Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/bin/docker-credential-desktop
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin  75 Feb  6  2022 /usr/local/bin/docker-credential-ecr-login@ -> /Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/bin/docker-credential-ecr-login
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin  77 Feb  6  2022 /usr/local/bin/docker-credential-osxkeychain@ -> /Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/bin/docker-credential-osxkeychain
```

If `docker-compose` fails as in the question, you can verify the actual commands called with `type docker` and `type docker-compose`, and the existance of the symlinks with `ls -l /usr/local/bin/docker*`.

If something seems off, you can then either delete and reinstall "Docker Desktop" or run `sudo ln -fs /Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/bin/* /usr/local/bin/` to fix the symlinks.

Answer (score 2):

It appears your syntax is incorrect, as the "-" between "docker" and "compose" is not correct. Try:

```
~ ➤ docker compose version
Docker Compose version v2.24.3-desktop.1
```

The `help` command shows `Usage:  docker [OPTIONS] COMMAND`.